# Eclipse CDT syntax coloring issues

Tags: c++, syntax-highlighting, eclipse-cdt, ubuntu-12.04

First off, I am running Eclipse 3.7.2 Build: M20120208-0800 on Ubuntu 12.04 (installed using the eclipse-* packages). I have applied all the updates available, but am still seeing the issue described below...

When I open a C++ file (*.h or *.cpp), it correctly highlights all object names in the file, but if I add new code to the file Eclipse will not apply coloring to the new code lines. However, if I restart Eclipse the new code will be correctly colored.

The indexer also appears to be working correctly because code completion seems to be working properly. The logs also appear to be clean. Has anyone seen this behavior before? Is there a good way to reset Eclipse to correct this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Get eclipse from eclipse.org. There nothing to install, just unpack archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this problem was to re-install the eclipse packages for Ubuntu 12.04. My syntax highlighting came back!